# Pandas query by local variable and get null values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some analysis on a beer dataset and was wanting to update NaN values of the "abv" column to use the mean values of the style.

Here's a couple of items in the dataset I want to update:
[image]

I'm trying to do this via a Pandas query and I can query by a specific style as a local variable:

```
df.query("styleName == @style")
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to add to this query a way to also return rows that have an "abv" of NaN. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [behaviour `NaN`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) - `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`, so `np.nan != np.nan` is `True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'styleName':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'abv':[np.nan,np.nan,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})
style = 'a'
print (df.query("styleName == @style & abv != abv"))
   B  C  D  F  abv styleName
0  4  7  1  a  NaN         a
```

Or boolean indexing:

```
print (df[(df['styleName'] == style) & (df['abv'].isnull())])
   B  C  D  F  abv styleName
0  4  7  1  a  NaN         a
```

Comment: Both work perfectly! I was trying to mix a boolean index within a query. Thanks!